# Sexing my beardies

Tags: reptiles

My beard dragons sex. Have two one goes crazy bobbing head up and down and black beard. The other one is bigger but no bobbing and does have like a beard . We put them in together and the smaller one bites and hold big one down then big one just tries to get away. The one we know is a male which is smaller won't stop bobbin but other one just stares at other one through tank. Need help

Answer (score 1):

A great way to sex your dragons is by passing a light through their tail, like this picture:
[image]

Head bobbing and puffing of the beard can be a dominance display or sexual, both situations can be harmful for your dragons so keep them separate at all times.